# Flutter flutter-pi video player udp stream

Tags: flutter, video-streaming, gstreamer

I run example from flutter plugin video_player on Flutter-Pi for Raspberry Pi 3B+

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.network('https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/bee.mp4')..initialize().then((_) {setState(() {});});
}
```

and it works.

opening file *.mp4

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.asset('assets/big_bunny.mp4');
    _controller.addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
    });
    _controller.setLooping(true);
    _controller.initialize().then((_) => setState(() {}));
    _controller.play();}
```

works too

BUT, I need opening RTP stream (UDP).

I tested gstreamer like this

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5000 caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, payload=(int)96" ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! videoscale ! autovideosink sync=false
```

and Raspberry Pi show frames from camera of the stream. So, I want to show it in flutter app on RaspberryPi. I supposed using URI like that

```
String pipeline = "udp://<remote-ip>:5000 ! application/x-rtp, media=video, clock-rate=90000, encoding-name=H264, payload=96 ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! videoscale ! autovideosink sync=false";
```

..

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(pipeline)..initialize();
}
```

BUT, I get error and nothing to display

```
[gstreamer video_player] Could not fetch duration. (gst_element_query_duration)
```

Gstreamer on RaspberryPi works good but I can't display in flutter-pi udp stream in local net

flutter-pi use gstreamer now, but can I open udp stream like pipeline in gstreamer?

Answer (score 0):

I'm tired of trying to use the gstreamer library with my linux app.
So I decided to use Process to run the gstreamer code

```
process = await Process.start('first gstreamer code ', [list of gstreamer items]);
    process.stdout.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((event) {
      stdout.writeln(event);
    });
```

Then you can receive your gstreamer video from **RowDatagramSocket** as a socket like this :

```
socket = await RawDatagramSocket.bind(InternetAddress('127.0.0.1'),
        port); //* socket to listen to UDP link on entered port
```

of course if you will receive a buffer of data as a Datagram type for that you will must specific the start and end pointers of images buffer you are received it from socket

```
 subscription = socket.listen((event) {
      //& when socket is listening will try to collect buffer :
      if (event == RawSocketEvent.read) {
        Datagram? datagram =
            socket.receive(); //* receive data in datagram variable.

        var dating =
            datagram?.data; //*  initail dating from datagram data if not null.

.
.
.
for statement to check buffer pointers 
.
.
.
//& add image buffer list to stream controller.
controller.add('list of image buffer');
```

if your gstreamer code like this :
**"gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0  ! video/x-raw,framerate=30/1 ! jpegenc ! multipartmux ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000"**
means the image format is jpeg your image pointers start and end as (ffd8 , ffd9) means you must check in buffer for **ff(or 255)** then **d8(or 216)** for start image pointer.

I think this in a nutshell might help you.

NOTE : i don't have any idea how can i do this for h264 format type if any one see that and have idea can be help us .